# Failed to Inject extended IdentityUser in view in AspNetCore 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I created an `ApplicationUser` which extends `IdentityUser`. Now I want to show/hide login and logout in view. So, I tried to inject `ApplicationUser` in `_signinPartial.cshtml` view but I get an error for ApplicationUser. 
It says `the type of namespace ApplicationUser can not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)`.
I found multiple blogs in internet and they did exactly the same way I did.

```
ApplicationUser.cs

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

I configured `ApplicationUser` in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

My _LoginPartial.cshtml looks like:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
@if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
  <li class="nav-item">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
        <button type="submit" style="width:auto"
                class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
            Logout @User.Identity.Name
        </button>
    </form>
  </li>
}
else
{
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="account" asp-action="index">
        Login
    </a>
  </li>
}
```

I've imported `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and `OAuth2Demo.Models` in `_ViewImports.cshtml` view.
I can work perfectly when I inject `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser`. I can do other actions using ApplicationUser like storing user in database, get claims for other purposes.

Comment: Is the `ApplicationUser` in the same namespace as `_LoginPartial`? If not you will probably need to add a `using` statement for that namespace.

Comment: I've added namespace in _ViewImports.cshtml.

Comment: You are stating that you added two other namespaces, but not the one for `ApplicationUser` - if you added more namespaces, please show us by adding it into the question. And is `_ViewImports.cshtml` included in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`. You are leaving out a lot of information needed to get a complete picture of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the type of namespace ApplicationUser can not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference).

> I've imported Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and OAuth2Demo.Models in _ViewImports.cshtml view

To troubleshoot the issue, please check if your `ApplicationUser` class is defined as below.

```
namespace OAuth2Demo.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
        //...
        //properties here
        //...
```

And please note that a `_ViewImports.cshtml` file can be placed within any folder, in which case ***it will only be applied to pages or views within that folder and its subfolders***. So please make sure your add `@using OAuth2Demo.Models` in correct `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Besides, you can try to specify a fully qualified name in `_signinPartial.cshtml`, then check if it can work well.

```
@inject SignInManager<OAuth2Demo.Models.ApplicationUser> signInManager
```

Comment: Actually, I resolved the issue later. It was the same reason you're telling.